# How can I get my submenus to disppear after a certain period?

Tags: javascript

I want to set time for my submenus to disppear after a certain period using JavaScript. My code is:

```
function buildsubmenus(){
    for (var i=0; i<menuids.length; i++){
        var ultags=document.getElementById(menuids[i]).getElementsByTagName("ul")

        for (var t=0; t<ultags.length; t++){
            ultags[t].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className="subfolderstyle"

            if (ultags[t].parentNode.parentNode.id==menuids[i]) 
                //if this is a first level submenu
                //dynamically position first level submenus to be width of main menu item
            ultags[t].style.left=ultags[t].parentNode.offsetWidth+"px"
    else 
                //else if this is a sub level submenu (ul)
                //position menu to the right of menu item that activated it
        ultags[t].style.left=ultags[t-1].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].offsetWidth+"px" 

            ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseover=function(){
                this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="block"
                if(this.getElementsByTagName("a").length  == '1'){
                    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="none"   
                }
            }

function wait(){
    setTimeout('times()', 5000)
}

ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout=function times(){
    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="none"
}
}
    for (var t= ultags.length-1; t>-1; t--){ //loop through all sub menus again, and use "display:none" to hide menus (to prevent possible page scrollbars
    ultags[t].style.visibility="visible"
    ultags[t].style.display="none"
    }
  }
}
```

and my function that I want to display after a certain time is `times()`, but whenever I do `onmouse` it calls it directly and it doesn't wait for the time to count.

Comment: Can you make the a little title clearer? I think it scares possible answerers away.

Comment: Donald: I made your question title more meaningful, this makes it more likely that you'll get a good answer, and helps make your question (and any answers) more useful to the SO community. Good luck with your query :)

Comment: thanx for reconstructing it..

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, you told to call time onmouseout!

```
ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout=function times(){
    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="none"
}
```

You should have done

```
var waitToDelete = function(){
    setTimeout(deleteList, 5000);
}

ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout= waitToDelete;

function deleteList()
{
   document.getElementById("Your Menu ID").getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: I *think* this is right - nothing calls wait() anyway and I've seen similar problems where onmouseover changes the layout such that it triggers an onmouseout, which seems likely here too

Comment: If i try to alert it in the deletelist() function to see if it will come there after the time specified it correctly alerts but it doesn't implement the code: this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="none"; so i dont know if you have any solution if this is because it doesn't maybe recognize the 'this' object

Comment: Indeed you are right, try document.getElementById("Your Menu ID").getElementsByTagName....

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your problem is that you are not referencing the correct function in your call to setTimeout. In other words, the call to the function in the setTimeout parameter is executed in the context of the window object, whereas your times() function is defined in the context of your buildSubmenus object (you may not have realized this but defining you wait() function and your times() function inside of the body of buildSubmenus means that the wait() and times() functions are only defined and valid inside local scope of the buildSubmenus function)

I was going to try to correct the code in your sample code but there are too many issues and with the rest of the context missing I think it would be best if I would just point you in the right direction. You need to learn and understand the concepts of [closures](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies) and [currying](http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-curry/) before you go about correctly implementing the code that you posted in the question.

Also, if you don't feel inclined to understanding the inner-workings of why your example doesn't work, I would suggest you take a look at a javascript framework that can handle all that for you such as [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/) or [jquery](http://jquery.com/).